# I added an about menu, and now I need help on how to bring info up on click

Tags: android

I had a image but cant up load it yet AHH

I was able to get the menu to work. My question is how to I make a msgbox pop up on click so I can put details about app and my self?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bigmos... For an about dialog I would just use the AlertDialog builder. I have [sample code](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/dialogs) here.

Comment: Thank you your tutorial was awesome and accurate, Can i use same code to bring up a notification? I want to let the user know data connection required.

Comment: @bigmos Thanks for the feedback! You could create a different alert and display it as in showDialog(DIALOG_NOTIFY_DATA_REQUIRED);

Comment: How to call it when app start. No prob on feedback you know your sh$%.:)

Comment: @bigmos You should be able call showDialog(i) in the onCreate(b) of the main app AFTER you initialize the variables. I learned to program in assembly, so I have had plenty of time to learn how to do things the wrong way!

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`. Really, this is all in the [development guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html). See also [Creating dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).